# Default Parameters in Function Definition, Syntax problems.

Tags: python, syntax, default-value

I am having an issue finding a straightforward answer to a question that I have.

I am coding a program that has some default values for certain parameters that do not end up being called by the user. My program is somewhat complicated so I decided to try a simplified problem.

```
def mult(x = 1, y = 2, z = 3):
    ans = x * y * z
    print(ans)

mult()
```

In this quick program, the function call would result in 6. Which makes sense because it goes to the default values I provided. My question is, how can I call this function if, for example, I wanted to define y and not any other variable? What would be the correct syntax in that situation.

My intuition was to call mult(x, 5, z) to indicate default values for x and z but a new value for y. I know that does not work and would like to know what the correct syntax would be.

Comment: `mult(y=7)` ....

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the parameter to supply by using `=` at the call site:

```
mult(y = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call it with keywords

```
mult(y=7) 

mult(z=55)

mult(z=12,y=16,x=5)

mult(x=15)
```

although as an aside its probably preferable to `return ans` instead of just printing it ...